# Find the asymptotes of $y=2x-\arccos(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Find the asymptotes of $y=2x-\arccos(1/x)$

How to solve this problem mathematically without sketching.

Answer (score 1):

as $x$ approaches +-infinity $y$ approaches the line $2x-1$ monotonically. This suggests that $y=2x-1$ is an asymptote

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

First find the domain of $f(x)=2x-\arccos\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)$. You should find $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)$.

Then find the limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ of $\arccos\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)$, which comes down to finding
$$\lim_{u\to 0^+}\arccos u\enspace\text{ and}\enspace\lim_{u\to 0^-}\arccos u.
$$

Comment: @Bernad Can it be solved by assuming the asymptote in the form $y=m\,x+c$ where compute $$
m=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{y}{x}$$ and $$c=\lim_{x\to\infty}(y-mx)$$ If yes, please help me to find the limit

Comment: Why complicate matters? You already have the value of $m$ in the equation: it's $2$. And $y - mx=\arccos \dfrac 1x$.

Comment: @Bernad $\lim_{u\to 0\pm}\arccos u=\pi/2$ Please write it more details what I shall do next

Comment: There are two different limits ( don't forget $\arccos u$ lies in $\bigl[-\pi/2, \pi/2\bigr]$). These limits are the values of $c$ (so you have two parallel asymptotes).

Comment: $\lim_{u\to 0+}\arccos u=+\pi/2$, $\lim_{u\to 0-}\arccos u=-\pi/2$

Comment: @user1942348: It's exactly that.